# How to add value and text both property to dropdown list

Tags: c#

I have three dropdown menu the  value part is in web.config.for  Drp_List3 dropdowm menu I have value and Text both but I want to show text value in dropdown but to concatenate I want value.Sry guys to bother or if I sound foolish.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {


        string server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SV"].ToString();
        string[] val1 = server.Split(',');
        foreach (string str1 in val1)
        {
            Drp_List1.Items.Add(str1);

        }

        string website = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["site"].ToString();
        string[] val2 = website.Split(',');
        foreach (string str2 in val2)
        {
            Drp_List2.Items.Add(str2);

        }

        string sitetype = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorLog"].ToString();
        string[] val3 = sitetype.Split(',');
        foreach (string str3 in val3)
        {

            Drp_List3.Items.Add(new ListItem(str3));

        }
        string sitetypedetail = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorLogType"].ToString();
        string[] val4 = sitetypedetail.Split(',');
        foreach (string str4 in val4)
        {
            Drp_List3.Items.Add(new ListItem(str4));
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Would have liked to help, but I think your question is pretty unclear, I can't seem to get the whole picture, where do you want to attach value and text ? why is there more code than your main concern ? is it relevant ?

Comment: The Text  i am putting in page_Load event, the vaue part is in web.config, my question is how can i add that value to text.can anyone plz help me with this.

Comment: @user2533029 looks like a simple string concatenation to me, check my updated answer please.

Comment: now in that dropdown not showing any thing , not text not value.Thanks all for help but I think mayme i didnt ask right question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this all over again.  For the Page_Load part, here is something to try:

```
Drp_List3.Items.Add("Website"+ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyStuff"]);
```

Where the `"MyStuff"` is the key in the `web.config` that you want to add for the `Drp_List3` set of values.

For the dropdowns that are further down in the code sample, I give you this to help with that:

I am presuming that the filename can come straight from the web.config and that other stuff can be done to generate all of the Text and Value portions for the `DropDownList` which has an `Items` collection you are trying to fill:

```
string filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filename"];
string TextPart = "c:\\mystuff\\"+filename;
string ValuePart = filename;
ListItem li = new ListItem(TextPart,ValuePart);
ddlValues.Items.Add(li);
```

This will give you a `ListItem` that you can add to the Items collection of the `DropDownList` so that the text portion of the option will be the `TextPart` and the value of the option will be the `ValuePart`.  Now, if you want something else to be set in the Text or Value, just do that prior to creating the `ListItem`.  Something else to note is that a `ListBox` is not the same as a `DropDownList`, as the former will just have a collection of values in it that is a straightforward `List` of text values rather than the `KeyValuePair` that a `DropDownList` has.  This is why you have to be careful with your language and terminology as I've done more than a few things with various classes that had similar names.

Comment: I want to show text part in dropdown menu but for concatenation i want my value part, by the above method both text and value part will be shown in dropdown menu.

Comment: I have a dropdown menu in which i have to show some value to concatenate with other and show a path that value is in web.config and show Text related with value, my question is how that text only show in dropdown not value but concatenate with value.sry if i phare my question poor, i am quiet new at this.

Comment: This works now i replying late but may be work for another person, I put in aspx page both value and text for dropdowm menu by add listitem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you meen something like this ?

```
DropDownListSearchPrices.Items[0].Value = DropDownListSearchPrices.Items[1].Text;
```

OR

```
DropDownListSearchPrices.Items[1].Text = DropDownListSearchPrices.Items[0].Value.toString();
```